# match content of two lists which contains a sentences inside them

Tags: python

there are 2 lists each of them have different length and i try to compare them but it returns no match

here is the code

```
text = open('tt.txt', 'r')
txt = text.read()
text.close()

i = 0
lis = ['Elephants are the biggest land animals in the world.',
   'Sunset is the time of day when our sky meets the outer space solar winds.',
   'Elephants are mammals as well as herbivores, meaning they only eat plants rather than meat.',
   'This happened more than once.',
   'As a police officer I was an obvious target and was baited whenever it seemed safe to do so. ',
   'The young Buddhist priests were the worst of all.There were several thousands of them in the town and none of '
   'them seemed to have anything to do except stand on street corners and jeer at Europeans.']

fulltext = txt.split(".")

print(fulltext)

for item in lis:
    for item1 in fulltext:
        if item == item1:
            print(item)
     else:
        print("no match")
```

results also look like this

output

```
/home/way/.virtualenvs/small_plsa/bin/python /home/way/LocalRepository/py/small_plsa/src/example.py
['IN MOULMEIN, IN LOWER BURMA, I was hated by large numbers of people--the only time in my life that I have been important enough for this to happen to me', ' I was sub-divisional police officer of the town, and in an aimless, petty kind of way anti-European feeling was very bitter', ' No one had the guts to raise a riot, but if a European woman went through the bazaars alone somebody would probably spit betel juice over her dress', ' As a police officer I was an obvious target and was baited whenever it seemed safe to do so', ' When a nimble Burman tripped me up on the football field and the referee (another Burman) looked the other way, the crowd yelled with hideous laughter', ' This happened more than once', ' In the end the sneering yellow faces of young men that met me everywhere, the insults hooted after me when I was at a safe distance, got badly on my nerves', ' The young Buddhist priests were the worst of all', ' There were several thousands of them in the town and none of them seemed to have anything to do except stand on street corners and jeer at Europeans', ' Sunset is the time of day when our sky meets the outer space solar winds', ' There are blue, pink, and purple swirls, spinning and twisting, like clouds of balloons caught in a blender', ' The sun moves slowly to hide behind the line of horizon, while the moon races to take its place in prominence atop the night sky', ' People slow to a crawl, entranced, fully forgetting the deeds that still must be done', ' There is a coolness, a calmness, when the sun does set', ' Elephants are the biggest land animals in the world', ' The African elephant is found on the continent of Africa and the Indian elephant is found in Asia', ' Elephants are mammals as well as herbivores, meaning they only eat plants rather than meat', '']
no match
no match
no match
no match
no match
no match

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**fulltext** is a list which is retrieved from **tt.txt** file and it contains the hole sentences from the text file in the form of list also **lis** is a list and it is per-defined on the code it also a sentences

Comment: There is no match found because in `lis` each string end with `dot (.)` and when you split your text file data , there is no `dot(.)` at the end of each sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This Working Code:

```
text = open('tt.txt', 'r')
txt = text.read()
text.close()

i = 0
lis = ['Elephants are the biggest land animals in the world.',
   'Sunset is the time of day when our sky meets the outer space solar winds.',
   'Elephants are mammals as well as herbivores, meaning they only eat plants rather 
   than meat.',
   'This happened more than once.',
   'As a police officer I was an obvious target and was baited whenever it seemed 
   safe to do so. ',
   'The young Buddhist priests were the worst of all.There were several thousands of 
   them in the town and none of '
  'them seemed to have anything to do except stand on street corners and jeer at 
   Europeans.']

lis = [str(val)[:-1] for val in lis]

fulltext = txt.split(".")
fulltext = [str(val).strip() for val in fulltext]

print(fulltext)

for item in lis:
    for item1 in fulltext:
        if item == item1:
            print(item)
    else:
        print("no match")
```

Answer (score 0):

`txt.split(".")` by definition will not have any items containing the `.` character. It also tends to leave leading spaces which aren't in `lis`. Removing these characters from the sides reveals matches:

```
if item.strip('. ') == item1.strip('. '):
```

Your `else` clause will always be triggered because the for loop contains no `break`. Even if you add one, it's not really adding anything useful to the program, so just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Python's `difflib` module.  It has useful tools for comparing text.

```
import difflib

text1 = 'ABCDE'
text2 = 'DEFGH'

for line in difflib.unified_diff(text1, text2):
    print(line)
```

#### Output:

```
--- 

+++ 

@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@

-A
-B
-C
 D
 E
+F
+G
+H
```